# ibmcloud functions, (openwhisk) .cant connect to redis using net core 3.1 Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.Pipelines

Tags: .net-core, redis, ibm-cloud, serverless, openwhisk

I'm trying to connect to IBM databases for redis instance from ibmcloud functions for days but i had no luck. I tried using ibmcloud supported version .netcore 2.2 and docker image core 3.1.

I can connect to redis without anyerrors from a local console app using code below.

I need your help. Thank you.

```
    public IbmRedisClient(JObject args)
    {
        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root);
        var base64 = (string)args.GetValue("redis_connection_certbase64");
        string connURL = (string)args.GetValue("redis_connection_string");
        connURL = connURL.Replace("$PASSWORD", PASSWORD);
        Console.WriteLine("base: " + base64);
        X509Certificate2 ca  = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(base64));
        var EndPointCollection = new EndPointCollection();
        var options = new ConfigurationOptions
        {
            AbortOnConnectFail = false,
            Ssl = true,
            ConnectRetry = 3,
            ConnectTimeout = 5000,
            SyncTimeout = 5000,
            DefaultDatabase = 0,
            Password = "testadminpassword"
        };
        options.EndPoints.Add(host, 32326);
        options.EndPoints.Add(host, 0);

        options.CertificateSelection += delegate
        {
            return ca;
        };
        try
        {
             ConnectionMultiplexer muxer = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(options);

             conn = muxer.GetDatabase();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Root certificate import failed: " + ex.Message+" "+ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            store.Close();
        }

    }
```

Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.Pipelines, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. Could not find or load a specific file. (0x80131621) System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.Pipelines, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. Could not find or load a specific file. (0x80131621)",
"2021-03-28T07:41:12.715551Z    stdout: File name: 'System.IO.Pipelines, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'",
"2021-03-28T07:41:12.715557Z    stdout: ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.Pipelines, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.",
"2021-03-28T07:41:12.715562Z    stdout: at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.LoadFromPath(IntPtr ptrNativeAssemblyLoadContext, String ilPath, String niPath, ObjectHandleOnStack retAssembly)",
"2021-03-28T07:41:12.715567Z    stdout: at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.LoadFromAssemblyPath(String assemblyPath)",
"2021-03-28T07:41:12.715572Z    stdout: at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile)",
"2021-03-28T07:41:12.715576Z    stdout: at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFromResolveHandler(Object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)",
"2021-03-28T07:41:12.715581Z    stdout: at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.InvokeResolveEvent(ResolveEventHandler eventHandler, RuntimeAssembly assembly, String name)",
"2021-03-28T07:41:12.715586Z    stdout: at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.OnAssemblyResolve(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String assemblyFullName)",
"2021-03-28T07:41:12.715590Z    stdout: at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(ConfigurationOptions configuration, TextWriter log)",

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding `<_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true</_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>` to your project file, haven't tried yet, but going by solution posted [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/1637#issuecomment-741834672) for a similar problem.

Comment: I've already tried this but it doesnt work on ibm cloud functions

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by downgrading StackExchange.Redis to a version that doesnt require Pipelines dependency.

Comment: If this workaround worked, then there's a chance you ran into a bug we noticed in the dotnet runtime, where transitive dependencies didn't work. Can you take a look and see if this matches what you experienced? https://github.com/apache/openwhisk-runtime-dotnet/issues/39